# I cant make the content appear inside the div

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var delivInfo = {};
var delivSummary = document.getElementById("deliverTo");

function processDeliveryInfo() {
    let prop;

    delivInfo.name = document.getElementById("nameinput").value;
    delivInfo.address = document.getElementById("addrinput").value;
    delivInfo.city = document.getElementById("cityinput").value;
    delivInfo.email = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
    delivInfo.phone = document.getElementById("phoneinput").value;
   

    for (prop in delivInfo) {
        delivSummary.innerHTML += "<p>" + delivInfo[prop] + "</p>";
    }
    alert(delivSummary.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
 <section id="blockStyle">
         <h2>Order Summary</h2>
         <h3>Deliver to</h3>
         <div id="deliverTo"></div>
         <h3>Order</h3>
         <div id="order"></div>
      </section>
```

Im trying to add the values from delivInfo object as content to deliverTo div but it wont appear on the page, when i use alert(delivSummary.innerHTML); it seems the values are there so im really confused

Comment: You never call `processDeliveryInfo`

Comment: How/where do you add your info in `delivInfo` in your code?

Comment: i have an event listener that calls this function when preview button is clicked function previewOrder() {
    processDeliveryInfo();
    document.getElementById("blockStyle").style.display = "block";
}

Answer (score 0):

check the code I have revised

```js
var delivInfo = {};
var delivSummary = document.getElementById("deliverTo");

function processDeliveryInfo() {
    let prop;

    delivInfo.name = document.getElementById("nameinput").value;
    delivInfo.address = document.getElementById("addrinput").value;
    delivInfo.city = document.getElementById("cityinput").value;
    delivInfo.email = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
    delivInfo.phone = document.getElementById("phoneinput").value;
   

    for (prop in delivInfo) {
        delivSummary.innerHTML += "<p>" + delivInfo[prop] + "</p>";
    }
    alert(delivSummary.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameinput" id="nameinput"></td><tr>
  <td>Address</td><td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addrinput" id="addrinput"></td><tr>
  <td>City</td><td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cityinput" id="cityinput"></td><tr>
  <td>Email</td><td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailinput" id="emailinput"></td><tr>
  <td>Phone</td><td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneinput" id="phoneinput"></td><tr>
  
      <td> </td><td> <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="processDeliveryInfo()">Process Info</button></td><tr>
      </table>

<section id="blockStyle">
         <h2>Order Summary</h2>
         <h3>Deliver to</h3>
         <div id="deliverTo"></div>
         <h3>Order</h3>
         <div id="order"></div>
      </section>
```